# On equivariant maps

Tags: equivariant-maps

It is well know the notion of [Equivariant map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map#Formalization) .

Now, consider the situation: $X$ and $Y$ being $G$- and $H$-sets, resp., and   a homomorphism $\varphi: G\to H$.

How is called a map $f:X\to Y$ satisfying $f(gx)=\varphi(g)f(x)$
?

Comment: It's also called equivariant, or $\varphi$-equivariant to be more precise.

Comment: I would not call $f$ an equivariant since $f$ is equivariant if the domain and the codomain of $f$ are acted upon by the same group $G$. I would call it $\varphi$-$\textit{equivariant}$.